# post on facebook wall after just like

Tags: facebook-like

Is it possible to post on FB users' wall after he likes my FB page with application (or site connected to FB application)? I mean without permissions request. Do I get access token after like at all?

Comment: You need to ask for `publish_stream` permission from user, if he accepts, you then get token...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't obtain an access token after a use like something on your site.

You would need to ask for permissions to obtain any info about the user, and if you want to post to the wall of the user automatically (which by the way would be considered spam and trigger the deactivation of your app).

An option would be to put a callback function when the user click the button like (using FB.Event.subscribe: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/), and trigger a publication popup (FB.ui, method: 'feed': https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/)

Comment: I'll need to post something at his wall say at his birthday. Will this be considered spam?

Comment: If it's the goal of the application and the user consents to it, then it will be fine. In this case, ask for the publish_stream permission.